# How can I use lettrine with parallel? Or should I use something else?

Tags: lettrine, parallel, drop-cap

I'm trying to set two versions of a text side-by-side and have worked out how to do it using parallel.

I'd also like to use drop caps on the first line.

When I do, however, parallel seems to stop working for that paragraph.
Here is the code I am trying, with it setting first correctly and then not:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{parallel,lettrine}

\begin{document}

\begin{Parallel}{}{}
    \ParallelLText{\noindent\emph{Wycliffe Bible}, 1382}
    \ParallelRText{\noindent\emph{Green's Literal Translation}, 1993}
    \ParallelPar

    \ParallelLText{In the bigynnyng God made of nouyt heuene and erthe.}
    \ParallelRText{In the beginning God created the heavens and the earth;}
    \ParallelPar

    \ParallelLText{$^{2}$Forsothe the erthe was idel and voide, and derknessis weren on the face of depthe; and the Spiryt of the Lord was borun on the watris.}
    \ParallelRText{$^{2}$and the earth being without form and empty, and darkness on the face of the deep, and the Spirit of God moving gently on the face of the waters,}
    \ParallelPar

\end{Parallel}
\vspace{2 cm}


\begin{Parallel}{}{}
    \ParallelLText{\noindent\emph{Wycliffe Bible}, 1382}
    \ParallelRText{\noindent\emph{Green's Literal Translation}, 1993}
    \ParallelPar

    \ParallelLText{\lettrine{I}{n} the bigynnyng God made of nouyt heuene and erthe.}
    \ParallelRText{\lettrine{I}{n} the beginning God created the heavens and the earth;}
    \ParallelPar

    \ParallelLText{$^{2}$Forsothe the erthe was idel and voide, and derknessis weren on the face of depthe; and the Spiryt of the Lord was borun on the watris.}
    \ParallelRText{$^{2}$and the earth being without form and empty, and darkness on the face of the deep, and the Spirit of God moving gently on the face of the waters,}
    \ParallelPar

\end{Parallel}

\end{document}
```

And the result of this example:

[image: MWE]

Can anybody show me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\linewidth` (used by `\lettrine`) has not the correct value.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{parallel}
\usepackage{lettrine}

\begin{document}

\begin{Parallel}{}{}
    \ParallelLText{\noindent\emph{Wycliffe Bible}, 1382}
    \ParallelRText{\noindent\emph{Green's Literal Translation}, 1993}
    \ParallelPar

    \ParallelLText{In the bigynnyng God made of nouyt heuene and erthe.}
    \ParallelRText{In the beginning God created the heavens and the earth;}
    \ParallelPar

    \ParallelLText{$^{2}$Forsothe the erthe was idel and voide, and derknessis weren on the face of depthe; and the Spiryt of the Lord was borun on the watris.}
    \ParallelRText{$^{2}$and the earth being without form and empty, and darkness on the face of the deep, and the Spirit of God moving gently on the face of the waters,}
    \ParallelPar

\end{Parallel}
\vspace{2 cm}


\begin{Parallel}{}{}
    \ParallelLText{\noindent\emph{Wycliffe Bible}, 1382}
    \ParallelRText{\noindent\emph{Green's Literal Translation}, 1993}
    \ParallelPar

    \ParallelLText{\setlength{\linewidth}{\hsize}\lettrine{I}{n} the bigynnyng God made of nouyt heuene and erthe. }
    \ParallelRText{\setlength{\linewidth}{\hsize}\lettrine{I}{n} the beginning God created the heavens and the earth;}
    \ParallelPar


    \ParallelLText{$^{2}$Forsothe the erthe was idel and voide, and derknessis weren on the face of depthe; and the Spiryt of the Lord was borun on the watris.}
    \ParallelRText{$^{2}$and the earth being without form and empty, and darkness on the face of the deep, and the Spirit of God moving gently on the face of the waters,}
    \ParallelPar

\end{Parallel}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Rather simpler than my fixing of the symptom. +1

Comment: Definitely the easiest to implement, thank you - and I think it helps me best understand how I might overcome other problems if I encounter them later on.

Answer (score 3):

Something of a manual workaround, using `minipage`s.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{parallel,lettrine}

\begin{document}

\begin{Parallel}{}{}
    \ParallelLText{\noindent\emph{Wycliffe Bible}, 1382}
    \ParallelRText{\noindent\emph{Green's Literal Translation}, 1993}
    \ParallelPar

    \ParallelLText{In the bigynnyng God made of nouyt heuene and erthe.}
    \ParallelRText{In the beginning God created the heavens and the earth;}
    \ParallelPar

    \ParallelLText{$^{2}$Forsothe the erthe was idel and voide, and derknessis weren on the face of depthe; and the Spiryt of the Lord was borun on the watris.}
    \ParallelRText{$^{2}$and the earth being without form and empty, and darkness on the face of the deep, and the Spirit of God moving gently on the face of the waters,}
    \ParallelPar

\end{Parallel}
\vspace{2 cm}


\begin{Parallel}{}{}
    \ParallelLText{\noindent\emph{Wycliffe Bible}, 1382}
    \ParallelRText{\noindent\emph{Green's Literal Translation}, 1993}
    \ParallelPar

    \ParallelLText{\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{2.4in}\lettrine{I}{n}
 the bigynnyng God made of nouyt heuene and erthe.\end{minipage}}
    \ParallelRText{\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{2.4in}\lettrine{I}{n}
 the beginning God created the heavens and the earth;\end{minipage}}
    \ParallelPar

    \ParallelLText{$^{2}$Forsothe the erthe was idel and voide, and derknessis weren on the face of depthe; and the Spiryt of the Lord was borun on the watris.}
    \ParallelRText{$^{2}$and the earth being without form and empty, and darkness on the face of the deep, and the Spirit of God moving gently on the face of the waters,}
    \ParallelPar

\end{Parallel}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Edit: I figured it out**

The `lettrine` manual has a hint  of a workaround (p.4)

> If  a list has  to  be  included  in  a  paragraph  starting  with  a  ‘lettrine’,  it  is necessary to add the command `\parshape=0` just after the end of the list.

Simply writing

```
 \ParallelLText{\lettrine{I}{n} the bigynnyng God made of nouyt heuene and erthe.\parshape=0}
```

doesn't *quite* work, as the drop cap ends up in the margin/gutter:
[image]

This looks rather like a bug in `lettrine`, and nothing to do with `parallel`, in that adding `parshape=0` puts the drop cap in the margin in trivial usage (and setting `lhang` is ignored with `parshape=0`):

```
\lettrine{T}{est} this is some long text that should wrap onto a second line.  It will end with \texttt{parshape=0}. \parshape=0
\lettrine{T}{est} this is some long text that should wrap onto a second line.  It \emph{does not} end with \texttt{parshape=0}.
```

[image]

Instead we create two new commands: `\ParallelLtextL` and `\ParallelRTextL` which accept 3 arguments: the 2 for `\Lettrine` and the rest of the parallel text.  There's also a new length `\LWidth` used to hold the width of the drop cap.

```
\newlength{\LWidth}
\newcommand{\ParallelLTextL}[3]{\settowidth{\LWidth}{\LettrineFont{#1}}%
    \ParallelLText{\lettrine{#1}{#2}#3\parshape=1 \LWidth \dimexpr\ParallelLWidth - \ParallelMainMidSkip\relax}%
}
\newcommand{\ParallelRTextL}[3]{\settowidth{\LWidth}{\LettrineFont{#1}}%
    \ParallelRText{\lettrine{#1}{#2}#3\parshape=1 0pt \dimexpr\ParallelRWidth - \LWidth\relax}%
}
```

Which we use as follows:

```
\ParallelLTextL{I}{n}{ the bigynnyng God made of nouyt heuene and erthe.}
\ParallelRTextL{I}{n}{ the beginning God created the heavens and the earth;}
```

[image]

Comment: BTW the case of `\parshape=0` causing problems is fixed (for paragraph text)  by instead issuing `\parshape=1 0pt \linewidth`.  I haven't tested it for lists.